# Equitable 4-colorings of planar triangulations

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, planar-graphs

In an
[equitable coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equitable_coloring)
of a graph $G$, the number of vertices in each color class differ
by at most $1$.
For example, left below is not an equitable coloring, while the
right graph is equitably colored.

---

[image: Equitable_s12_n20.jpg]

---

(I don't know if there is an equitable coloring for the left graph.
Changing the topmost 3 to a 4 makes it more balanced but still
not equitable.)

> ***Q***. Are there structural properties for planar
> trianguations that guarantee the existence of an equitable
> $4$-coloring?

By a *triangulation* I mean all faces, but possibly not the outer face,
are triangles (as in the above examples).
[As per @GordonRoyle's comment, these are known in the literature as
"near triangulations."]
It is relatively easy to identify classes of triangulations
that cannot be equitably colored, e.g., wheel graphs:

[image: Wheel.jpg]

But I am finding it more difficult to identify classes that can be
equitably $4$-colored.
There is literature on equitable coloring of planar graphs,
but often triangulations are excluded.<sup>1</sup>
My sense is that it should be easier for triangulations.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Nakprasit, Keaitsuda, and Kittikorn Nakprasit.
"Equitable colorings of planar graphs without short cycles."
*Theoretical Computer Science* 465 (2012): 21-27.
[Earlier arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0379).

Comment: I think *near triangulation* is the most commonly used term for a triangulation of a polygon.

Comment: @GordonRoyle: Thanks; did not know that. I'm working with Delaunay triangulations (those examples derive from DTs).

Comment: Most likely it is NP-complete to decide whether an equitable 4-coloring exists or not. Here I've shown that the related problem of determining the domination number is NP-complete: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00596

Comment: If you consider a triangulation obtained from a triangle by repeatedly adding a vertex in a (triangular) face and joining it to the 3 vertices of the face, then the resulting graph is planar and uniquely 4-colorable. Depending on the faces you chose you can skew the distribution of colors 1,2,3,4 arbitrarily, and once you have done that you can triangulate faces arbitrarily (by adding a small fraction of vertices, in such a way that the distribution stays arbitrarily far from being equitable). The class of triangulations you obtain this way is very large and does not have a real structure.

Comment: @LouisEsperet: Very nice observations---Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, the best known result for the equitable coloring of planar graphs is that every planar graph with maximun degree $\Delta\ge 9$ can be equitably colored with $\Delta$ colors. Maybe you can also apply some known results on the equitable colorings of $d$-degenerate graphs.